# How can I use Django DeleteView in my template

Tags: django

I am using Django DeleteView in a template and I've created a url & view. But it shows "Generic detail view EmployeeDeleteView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf." I was looking on django docs, and looks like that DeleteViews are coupled with the models. How can I use Django DeleteView here. If any one help me please.

views.py

```
class EmployeeDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Employee
    success_url = 'create_employee'
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

urls.py

```
path('delete_employee/<int:id>', EmployeeDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete_employee'),
```

Delete Button

```
<button class="deletebtn show-form-delete" type="submit">
                                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>&nbsp;<a
                                        onclick="return confirm('Are you sure do you want to delete {{i.name}}')"
                                        href="{% url 'delete_employee' i.id %}">Delete</a></button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'delete_employee' i.id %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<button class="deletebtn show-form-delete" type="submit" value="DELETE" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure do you want to delete {{i.name}}')">
    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
    Delete</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need an entry in the urls.py like so with pk instead of `<int:id>`:

```
path('delete_employee/<int:pk>', EmployeeDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete_employee'),
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-date-based/

Comment: Then I want to make the changes in the button url also

Comment: Could you include that in your main question and give more detail of how you want it to change please?

Comment: Thank you for you great help Sir

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem!
The Generic view will look for an 'int' valued named 'pk' to delete.

Therefore:

`path('delete_employee/<int:pk>', EmployeeDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete_employee'),`

should fix your problem!